# Double scroll in ie 7 with ul

Tags: internet-explorer-7, scroll, html-lists

I have a problem with double scroll in IE 7 with my ul/li tree. Only I can do now in my case is that I remove scroll generated by IE but my real scroll donot work- it doesnot scroll the tree of elements. This is the short version of my tree:
What should I do for my scroll?

```
<ul id="pref1_tree" class="tree ui-widget-daredevel-checkboxTree ui-widget ui-widget content">
  <li id="rootMultiSelect" class="expanded">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-se"></span>
    <input id="pref1_chb_0" type="checkbox" value="0" name="pref1_lvlchb">
    <label id="pref1_label_0">Российская Федерация</label>
    <ul style="">
      <li id="rootMultiSelect" class="expanded">
      <li id="rootMultiSelect" class="expanded">
      <li id="rootMultiSelect" class="expanded">
      <li id="rootMultiSelect" class="expanded">
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-se"></span>
      <input id="pref1_chb_8" type="checkbox" value="8" name="pref1_lvlchb">
      <label id="pref1_label_8">Кавказский ф.о.</label>
      <ul style="">
        <li class="leaf">
        <li class="leaf">
        <li class="leaf">
        <li class="leaf">
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```